# organise visual studio vb.net sub-routines alphabetically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i am new to visual studio 2019. i have created a windows forms project and am using vb.net. however, i have noticed that every day when i add code to the project form controls, they are not organised in alphabetical order. it seems new subroutines are organised based on the day i added them. See below example;

```
Private Sub PtPhone_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles PtPhone.KeyPress
    If (Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) AndAlso (Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))) Then e.Handled = True        
End Sub

Private Sub NOKPhone_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles NOKPhone.KeyPress
    If (Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) AndAlso (Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))) Then e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Coming from Access VBA background, these routines are organised alphabetically such that NOKPhone_KeyPress comes before PtPhone_KeyPress in the VBA editor. This makes it easy to look for and find a sub routine easily. Is there a way i can force visual studio to also organise these sub routines alphabetically?

Comment: It's rather pointless trying to arrange your methods alphabetically. The navigation bar at the top of the code window lists them in alphabetical order and you should use that to navigate anyway. It's easier and faster even if the code was arranged that way.

Comment: Did you try to organize your code using the #region preprocessor directive? Grouping your methods according to their functionality is a lot better than searching your code alphabetically.

Comment: what is #region preprocessor directive?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/directives/region-directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the top of the code window, in the 3 dropdowns:

[image]